# How can i hide a Column group when I use pagebreak

Tags: reporting-services, report, expression, builder, ssrs-2012

I have made a matrix report in SSRS with two column groups. I have added one of the column group also in the Row groups to use page break so I can have each column group on a separate page.

And you see in the following pictures the preview of what has happened with the output.

[Page One](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qjj5x.png)

[Page Two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3ztO.png)

You see that the page break has worked but it doesn’t hide the other column that shouldn’t be present.
Does somebody has a clue how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it with the list object in the toolbox.

I have put the matrix in the list and used a page break on the list.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think just adding a page break will hide the column group's visibility.  In SSRS, you can set visibility of a column group based on a condition. Right click on the column group, select Group Properties, Select "Visibility", and "Show and Hide Based on Expression".

You could set an expression based on a field or parameter value. For example, if a parameter value is such, the visibility is true, else false.  Example:

=IIF(Parameters!"PARAMNAME".Value.Equals(value),false,true)

I would think in your case, if some a field was null or blank, hide the column group. The page break will take care of itself.